# How to parse last character of a field and replace with another character in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have data in a column 'fruits' like this:

```
apple/green/
apple/red/
apple/brown
```

what i need to do is remove the '/' character at the end in rows 1 and 2. No change needs to be done in the 3rd row. My output should be

```
apple/green
apple/red
apple/brown
```

I have tried doing this..

```
b = foreach a generate (fruits), ENDSWITH(fruits,'/')==true ?    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(fruits, (INT)LAST_INDEX_OF(fruits, '/'), (INT)SIZE(fruits)),'');
```

Basically I am trying to replace the '/' symbol with space ' ' in the ending.

But i am getting error with this command. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bincond](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators) operator has this synthax:

```
(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false)
```

Therefore, `else` part is mondatory and write like this :

```
b = foreach a generate (fruits), ENDSWITH(fruits,'/')?    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(fruits, (INT)LAST_INDEX_OF(fruits, '/'), (INT)SIZE(fruits)),'') :fruits ;
```

Or more easier, think about using [REPLACE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#replace) function :

```
b = foreach a generate REPLACE(fruits,'[/]$','');
```

Comment: Hi i tried the second method (regex) and it worked. Thank you!